# Smallest value of n such that the product $n!$ ends in at least 10 zeros.

Tags: factorial

What is the smallest value of $n$ such that the product $n!$ ends in at least 10 zeros?

I tried to do this by multiplying each number but it didn't work. Please help.

Comment: If a number ends in $k$ (or more) zeros, what does that tell you about its prime factorisation?

Comment: Try computing the number of trailing zeros of $n!$ without actually computing $n!$.

Comment: Consequence: exactly 11 zeroes is impossible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint**: $10$ consists of the factors $2$ and $5$. How often do those factors arise as you increase the value of $n$? How many of them do you need to get a number with 10 zeros at the end (meaning it is divisible by $10^{10}$)?